# xcode NSMutableArray sqlite3_column_double

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, sqlite, nsmutablearray, double

I have a database containing names (string) and price (double) values.
In xcode I created a view controller containing a mutable array.
Then to add names and price in the array I have the code

```
viewController *vc = [[viewController alloc] init];
vc.name =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,0)];
vc.price=sqlite3_column_double(sqlStatement,1);
```

The vc.name line works fine but at sqlite3_column_double I get the following error:
Assigning to 'double *' from incompatible type 'double'.
I have used sqlite3_column_double because for integers I use sqlite3_column_int.
Must I use something else for double type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have declared your view controller as:

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *name;
    double *price
}
...
@end
```

You obviously meant `double price` and not `double *price`.

Comment: omg I had it as NSNumber at first and forgot to remove * after changing it to double, what a stupid carelessness.                 thank a lot